# Selecting specifie row in Asp

Tags: c#, asp.net, database

I want to get a specific row from my data base in my asp.
I am programming on visual studio , with C# ON ASP. my problem is that I use this code.

```
 string cmdstr = "select top 5 name,id from Laptop order by id desc";
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(cmdstr, cn);
```

I want to get top 5 laptops from my database. in here I get them. but I don't know how to use them. either each of the codes below here doesn't work.

```
OleDbDataReader dr;
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
dr.GetString(0);
```

in the code above I can get the last one , but what if I want to get the others too?? I want to have top five. how can I say getstring the second row of the column 0. and then the third and then...
I know the answer is somewhere out there but I've searched for 1 hour and hopelessly started a question here.

p.s: non of the code below work for topsecond top third and ...

```
dr[0];
dr.GetValue(0);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with:

```
   ...
    using (var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (dr.Read()) //for each item in the datatable
        {
            dr.GetString(0);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code will help you

```
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
  name = reader["name"].ToString().Trim(); // get the name of item
  id  = reader["id"].ToString().Trim(); // get the id of item
}
reader.Close();
conn.Close();
```